# jQuery .get isn't working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the .get function to nab a text file and send an alert with the contents, but nothing's happening. This is the code I'm using.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("button").click(function() {
        .get("file.txt", function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a webserver? If not, then that is what you are doing wrong.

Comment: does the file definitly exist on the server in that location and is accessible?
Look in firebug or similar for any errors

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the commenters aren't right and you are using a webserver (either way, really), you are missing `$` from your `get` call

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("button").click(function() {
        $.get("file.txt", function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```